# Suggested edit popup gives poor layout in narrow windows

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, usability, popups

If the viewport is not a bit **wider than than the full width of the page layout**, then the suggested edit review popup from clicking “edit (n)” buries some or all of its controls, particularly including the top-left ⊗ close button. Furthermore, **resizing the window does not cause the popup to reposition itself** so this is an unrecoverable problem without reloading the page (or using the undocumented <kbd>esc</kbd> to dismiss). The first time I saw this, I assumed it was *designed* to force the user to review an edit.

I request the following fixes:

- The left edge of the popup should be kept at or to the right of the edge of the page, thus ensuring that the popup is fully accessible via scrolling (note that browsers allow scrolling rightward but not leftward).
- I'll skip arguing for responsive design and just say that the edit popup should be *no wider than the rest of the page*, including the close button.

#### Examples:

Nearly full-width window loses ⊗ button:

[image]

A window the width of the left column loses many controls:

[image]

And in case you're wondering: No, I'm not using an ancient portrait monitor. I'm using a 1440×900 widescreen laptop, and I've got more to do with my time and my screen than just browse SO.

Comment: It's awful on a mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made the following changes:

- In browsers that support the CSS `calc()` function, the popup will now stay horizontally centered when you resize the window.
- In browsers that don't support `calc()` (out of our officially supported browsers, that's only Opera and Safari 5), we at least ensure that the popup's left edge is visible, and not eternally hidden beneath the left edge of the window.

This will go live with the next build.

Comment: Could we change it so they are stacked vertically on the responsive mobile site?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Since I don't work for Stack Exchange anymore, it would probably make sense to leave this comment elsewhere or make a full feature request if you want the make sure it gets seen by the powers that be 

Comment: Oh okay! It's a pretty old issue, so maybe i'll ask a new question.